# Show the modal only when checkbox is checked and input is deleted and empty

Tags: jquery

Having trouble with the code, I appreciate your response in advance. What I'm trying to do is:
1. When the checkbox is checked and the mobile number field is not blank, then when the customer tries to delete the number then it should alert when focus out.
2. When the checkbox is checked and the mobile number field is already blank, then it should not show an alert when focus out.

```js
var textCheckboxChecked = $("input[id$='CheckboxPhone']").is(":checked");
    $('#profileCell').on('focusout', function() {
      if (($(this).val().length < 1) && textCheckboxChecked) {
       alert("test"); //When I delete the existing numer in input, then on focusout, alert works
          // That should not show alert on focusout when no number is available at all.
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-msg-phoneus="This phone number is invalid. Please enter a 10 digit number." autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control input-lg js-profileContact valid" value="214-456-6189" name="profileCell" id="profileCell" data-profilecontact="2144566189"
  data-profilecontactformat="214-456-6189">

<br><br>

<input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" id="customerServiceCheckboxPhone" name="customerServiceCheckboxPhone" checked="checked" class="valid">
<label class="checkbox-check" tabindex="0" for="customerServiceCheckboxPhone">Checkbox</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#profileCell").focusout(function(){
  if ($("#customerServiceCheckboxPhone").is(':checked')==true && $("#profileCell").val()=="") { 
        alert("mobile Number is mandatory"); 
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-msg-phoneus="This phone number is invalid. Please enter a 10 digit number." autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control input-lg js-profileContact valid" value="214-456-6189" name="profileCell" id="profileCell" data-profilecontact="2144566189"
  data-profilecontactformat="214-456-6189">

<br><br>

<input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" id="customerServiceCheckboxPhone" name="customerServiceCheckboxPhone" checked="checked" class="valid">
<label class="checkbox-check" tabindex="0" for="customerServiceCheckboxPhone">Checkbox</label>
```

Comment: but this works but I was looking for point 2 answer aswell.
If mobile is already present in the account and checkbox is also already checked then the above solution is ok.
Mobile is not mandatory, so after removing mobile and saving. When page will be reloaded, then when I click on mobile input and focusout, then it will show the alert whcih should now

Comment: which should not*